# Child/young adult story, alien with tentacles ending in clamps/crab claws

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to find the name of a novel I read a while ago, at least 10 years, probably more.

The details are a bit blurry but I remember some of them, like the cover.

It involves an alien species, I can't remember whether they are antagonists or not.
If I remember correctly, they are plant-like and the trees' 'branches' end in crab-like claws/clamps.

From what I remember of the cover :
First, it was the french one, so the original might be very different.
Secondly, It featured one of the aliens I described, as well as the protagonist. He had an oval face as well as a round nose, like Twinsen in Little Big Adventure.

I also remember him in a spacesuit, with the risk of having the aliens piercing it.

This is not a lot to go on, and I might of course be misremembering a lot of details, but the community is often very resourceful :-)

Comment: No idea what this is, but +1 for Twinsen :)

Comment: Larklight by Philip Reeve has a cover somewhat similar to what you describe here: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1118655.Larklight

Comment: thanks @DafyddNZ but that's not it. The story does not fit and the cover I have in mind has a simpler artstyle.